# Visual Studio 2010 and Framework Versions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I started a new job where I have to work with  several project built with the .NET framework 2 3 and 3.5.

Is possible to work on these projects only with visual studio 2010 or I need the older versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely target .NET 2, 3.0 and 3.5 from VS2010.

I advise you to have those versions of the framework installed *before* you install VS2010 though. It may make no difference, but my experience is that installing related products in chronological release order is *usually* a good idea.

If you have colleagues working with VS2008 who need to work on the same code, that will make your life a little more interesting, but it's still manageable. (You can share project files but not solution files, so long as you're careful.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VS 2010 (and VS2008) are multi-targetting, and can target any of those (and ideally stop you doing something stupid like include a reference that doesn't exist in your target platform).

However! There are some internal bug-fixes / changes / etc, which mean that somebody running 2.0 sees a different result to someone running 2.0 SP2 (because they've got later runtimes installed). There are even some types that exist in SP2 and not earlier. So you may want to test on a *vanilla* 2.0 machine if you need to support that. It may not be enough (in some edge cases) to just target 2.0 but test on a fully-up-to-date machine.

Answer (score 1):

If the existing projects were built with vs2005/2008 and there is no one else working on them, sure upgrade the project files to vs2010.

But if there are other people working on the projects who dont have vs2010, it is usually better to use the same build environment that they do.